# Why are the inputs added in this seq2seq Model?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, seq2seq

I've been trying to understand this example code on keras about seq2seq2.

Link: https://blog.keras.io/a-ten-minute-introduction-to-sequence-to-sequence-learning-in-keras.html

If I'm understanding it the `decoder_model` below has the input(s) is:
`decoder_inputs` and `decoder_states_inputs` where `[decoder_inputs]` is supposed to be used as the "actual" input and `decoder_states_inputs` initializes the lstm layer's state.

When the model is created the two inputs which are seemingly used for different things are combined with the "+" operator. How does `Model()` differentiate between the two?

```
encoder_model = Model(encoder_inputs, encoder_states)

decoder_state_input_h = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_state_input_c = Input(shape=(latent_dim,))
decoder_states_inputs = [decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]
decoder_outputs, state_h, state_c = decoder_lstm(
    decoder_inputs, initial_state=decoder_states_inputs)
decoder_states = [state_h, state_c]
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_outputs)
decoder_model = Model(
    [decoder_inputs] + decoder_states_inputs,
    [decoder_outputs] + decoder_states)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are summing `list` objects, not values.

- `decoder_states_inputs` is a `list`. (Made of `[decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]`)
- `[decoder_inputs]` is a `list` (look at the `[]`)

A `list + list` is just a concatenation of the two lists.

So: `[decoder_inputs] + [decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]`
Is equal to: `[decoder_inputs, decoder_state_input_h, decoder_state_input_c]`

This is just the list of inputs for the model. You always need to pass all the inputs in a list to create a model.